What is the actual MDX type for react?
Do you use mdx for react? what is the actual MDX type? I can't find it.
I have this main component:
'use client'

import styles from "./main.module.css";
import React from "react";
import "./main"


export class MainProps {
    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public contentStack: React.JSX.Element[] = [],
        public sectionOrArticle: "section" | "article" = "section",
    ) {
    }
}

export default function Main(props: { prop: MainProps }): React.JSX.Element {
    if (!props.prop.contentStack) {
        return (
            <main className={styles.main}>
                <h2>{props.prop.title}</h2>
            </main>
        )
    }
    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <h2>{props.prop.title}</h2>
            {
                props.prop.sectionOrArticle !== "article" ?
                    props.prop.contentStack.map((item) => (
                        <section key={props.prop.contentStack!.indexOf(item)}>
                            {item}
                        </section>
                    )) : props.prop.contentStack.map((item) => (
                        <article key={props.prop.contentStack!.indexOf(item)}>
                            {item}
                        </article>
                    ))
            }
        </main>
    )

}

that uses a MainProps struct that I've defined, but in it's contentStack field, I want an array of the MDX type, but i don't know how to specify that. I currently use this React.JSX.Element type which works since MDX needs to be that type, but can't I be more specific, since i only want MDX in this array.
This is how I use it currently:
'use client'

import TaskContent from "./task.mdx"
import React from "react";
import Header from "@/app/components/Header/header"
import Main, {MainProps} from "@/app/components/Main/main"
import "./main"

export default function Index(): React.JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div id={"root"}>
            <Header/>
            <Main prop={
                new MainProps(
                    "Sum all numbers till the given one",
                    [
                        TaskContent({}),
                    ],
                    "article",
                )
            }/>
        </div>
    );
}


I would guess ReactNode

ty for your reply @Konrad but wouldn't that be as generic as the type i'm using now, I guess, I'm looking for something more specific to MDX, like the JSX.Element equivalent of it, if that makes sense
